# How to get thumb icon of swing jslider?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I need to get the thumb icon which is used to select range in Jslider. How to get only the thumb icon from Jslider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
Icon icon = defaults.getIcon("Slider.horizontalThumbIcon");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that only works for some LAFs--many of them draw the icon dynamically.

Comment: @Michael My first thought was "Print Screen" but I thought that was a bit dry at the time, maybe not so. :)